# IntentService fails to run in certain situations

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I got a problem. Every once in a while, the IntentService `UpdateService02` fails to run. I put log entries in so I could debug and here's what I get...

> 02-28 21:37:32.461: Main - Broadcast Sent
>
> 02-28 21:37:32.484: BroadcastReceiver - Main Started; Set Alarm
>
> 02-28 21:37:32.539: BroadcastReceiver - Received AlarmService
>
> 02-28 21:38:32.500: BroadcastReceiver - Received AlarmService

Usually this should happen:

> 02-28 21:37:32.461: Main - Broadcast Sent
>
> 02-28 21:37:32.484: BroadcastReceiver - Main Started; Set Alarm
>
> 02-28 21:37:32.539: BroadcastReceiver - Received AlarmService
>
> 02-28 21:38:32.500: UpdateService -- onHandleIntent()

Any ideas? Here's my Broadcast Receiver code...

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int INTERVAL = 60*1000; // check every 60 seconds

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver - Received Boot Completed; Set Alarm");
            
                setRecurringAlarm(context);
            }else if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Main.BROADCAST_STARTUP)){
                Log.v(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver - Main Started; Set Alarm");
            
                setRecurringAlarm(context);
            }else{
                Log.v(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver - Received " + intent.getAction());
            }
        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver - Received AlarmService");
        
            Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService02.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }

    private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent receiver = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), INTERVAL, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

Intent Service:

```
public class UpdateService02 extends IntentService {

    static DefaultHttpClient mClient = Client.getClient();
    private static final int LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION = 100;

    public UpdateService02() {
        super("UpdateService02");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "UpdateService -- onHandleIntent()");
    
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response;
            response = mClient.execute(httpget);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        
            Intent i = new Intent(BROADCAST_UPDATE);  
            i.putExtra("text", in.readLine().toString() + " updated");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might be I need to set the intentservice startup's context to be the applications, but I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Where have you put the UpdateService -- onHandleIntent() log? in onStartCommand() service?

Comment: I thought that might up come, let me edit it to show my IntentService.

Comment: when the IntentService is not fired did u check if the service is already running?

Comment: It's always running, I believe. But this hasn't been a problem before. Another problem I've ran into is the IntentService with the HTTPClient works fine and then when I switch over to Wifi the HTTPClient gets an UnknownHostException. Could that mean it's trying to execute the HTTPClient call, never finishes and that's why I can't start it up again?

Comment: I've also stopping the service from the Android settings, and it still doesn't start up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem...

I changed this:

```
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = mClient.execute(httpget);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    Intent i = new Intent(BROADCAST_UPDATE);  
    i.putExtra("text", in.readLine().toString() + " updated");
    sendBroadcast(i);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
```

to this:

```
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = mClient.execute(httpget);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    Intent i = new Intent(BROADCAST_UPDATE);  
    i.putExtra("text", in.readLine().toString() + " updated");
    sendBroadcast(i);
    in.close();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
```

Sometimes the reader would get "clogged" up and the next time it got called it would still be stuck trying to work on the last request. Adding `in.close();` made sure I closed it after every usage. Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

A service will be started only once. If you call startService() for a already started service there will not be any effect. Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html.

```
A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity) starts it by
calling startService(). Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely,
even if the component that started it is destroyed.
```

When the service is not running, the intent should work properly.

Regarding

```
IntentService with the HTTPClient works fine and then when I switch over to Wifi the HTTPClient gets an UnknownHostException.
```

UnknownHostException occurs when there is no proper net connection. Check if the net connection is proper.

Comment: Two things...
1) IntentService is a special case of service. It will queue requests and stop itself when all requests are processed. If you call startService Multiple times, and the service is already running, its onStart method will be called everytime, onCreate will call only once if it is not already present. I'm pretty sure my IntentService ends after it finishes its work, even still onHandle would be called even if it was already running, would it not?

Comment: 2) I researched the UnknownHostException and what causes it, however the internet connection works fine. All other applications continue to successfully access the internet. And I have the INTERNET permission in my manifest, which is the only other cause of this problem. I even spent time researching if there was a permission required to use a wifi connection to access the internet.

Comment: HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("ht'tp://subdomain.domain.com/time.php"); 'Added so it wouldn't turn into a link.